# "Tab Slide Out" plug-in not visible in IE8 or lower

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have been working on a page that includes a "Tab Slide Out" jquery plug-in as well as a "Wow Slider" plug-in. I have both of these items working properly in all browsers except for IE8 and lower.

The tab image should show on the right hand side of the page and show above the Wow Slider when it is expanded. At the moment this happens in all of the browsers except IE 8 or lower. In these browsers the tab does not display at all.

The link for the page with all code is available here: http://www.naturalchanges.com/index2.html.

I have tried rearranging the jquery and java calls to get everything to load properly, but if you move the calls around the tab will load and the Wow Slider will not function properly.

Comment: (offtopic) WowSlider does anything but let the user concentrate on the page content. P.S: JAVA !== JAVASCRIPT